# Creating .dat files for Arrays

Tags: maven, swing, arraylist

/*I am trying to save ArrayLists inside a .dat file but I am encountering the error that the said Arrays are not being transfered inside the .dat files. It either creates the files as being empty or doesnt create them. I've copied the files from another program that have an Array written on them and it works but for my Maven Proyect its giving me issues.*/

````
import ClasesUsuarios.Clientes;
import ClasesUsuarios.Compra;
import ClasesUsuarios.FuncionUsuarios;
import ClasesUsuarios.FuncionesGraficas;
import ClasesUsuarios.Productos;
import ClasesUsuarios.Proveedores;
import ClasesUsuarios.Usuarios;
import ClasesUsuarios.Venta;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author nombr
 */
public class ProyectoUsuarios2 {
    
    


    static File fichUsuarios=new File("usuarios.dat");
    static File fichClientes=new File("clientes.dat");
    static File fichProveedores=new File("proveedores.dat");
    static File fichArticulos=new File("articulos.dat");
    static File fichCompras=new File("compras.dat");
    static File fichVentas=new File("ventas.dat");
   
   
    static{
        
        createFileIfNotExists(fichUsuarios);
        createFileIfNotExists(fichClientes);
        createFileIfNotExists(fichProveedores);
        createFileIfNotExists(fichArticulos);
        createFileIfNotExists(fichCompras);
        createFileIfNotExists(fichVentas);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        
        FuncionUsuarios gestion = new FuncionUsuarios();
        
        gestion.AddUsuario("MPC", "nombre2727@gmail.com", 'M', "MPC", "12345", 0);
        
        if (gestion.PasswordTries()) {
            
            ArrayList<Clientes> clientes;
            ArrayList<Compra> compra;
            ArrayList<Productos> productos;
            ArrayList<Proveedores> proveedor;
            ArrayList<Usuarios> usuarioApp;
            ArrayList<Venta> ventas;
            
            usuarioApp = leerUsuariosApp();
            clientes = leerClientes();
            proveedor = leerProveedores();
            productos = leerArticulos();
            ventas = leerVentas();
            compra = leerCompras();
            
            new MenuPrincipal(usuarioApp, clientes, proveedor, productos, ventas, compra).setVisible(true);
        }else{
            new VentanaError("Usten no tiene acceso a la Aplicacion!").setVisible(true);
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    public static ArrayList<Usuarios> leerUsuariosApp() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        
      ArrayList<Usuarios> arr=new ArrayList<>();
           
      if (fichUsuarios.exists())
      {
          try (FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(fichUsuarios); 
                  ObjectInputStream regUsuario = new ObjectInputStream(fIn)) 
          {
              
                  try
                  {
                    arr=(ArrayList<Usuarios>) regUsuario.readObject();
                  }catch (IOException e)
                  {
                   new VentanaError("Hubo algún problema al leer fichero de usuarios de disco " + e.getMessage()).setVisible(true); 
                  }
           
           fIn.close();
           regUsuario.close();
          }     
          
          
      }
      else 
      {
        fichUsuarios.createNewFile();
      }
            
      
      return(arr);
      
    } 
    
public static ArrayList<Clientes> leerClientes() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        ArrayList<Clientes> clientes = new ArrayList<>();

        try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("clientes.dat"))) 
        {
            clientes = (ArrayList<Clientes>) inputStream.readObject();
        } 
        catch (EOFException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error", "Se alcanzó el final del archivo inesperadamente.");
        
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","Error de E/S al leer el archivo.");
        
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","No se encontró la clase necesaria para deserializar los objetos.");
        }

         return clientes;
    }

    
    public static ArrayList<Proveedores> leerProveedores() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        ArrayList<Proveedores> proveedores = new ArrayList<>();

        try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("proveedores.dat"))) 
        {
        proveedores = (ArrayList<Proveedores>) inputStream.readObject();
        
        } 
        catch (EOFException e)
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error", "Se alcanzó el final del archivo inesperadamente.");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","Error de E/S al leer el archivo.");
        
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","No se encontró la clase necesaria para deserializar los objetos.");
            
        }

        return proveedores;
    }
    
   public static ArrayList<Productos> leerArticulos() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
   {
        ArrayList<Productos> articulos = new ArrayList<>();

        try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("articulos.dat"))) 
        {
            articulos = (ArrayList<Productos>) inputStream.readObject();
        } 
        catch (EOFException e) 
        {   
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error", "Se alcanzó el final del archivo inesperadamente.");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","Error de E/S al leer el archivo.");
        
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","No se encontró la clase necesaria para deserializar los objetos.");
        }

        return articulos;
    }
    
   public static ArrayList<Venta> leerVentas() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
   {
        ArrayList<Venta> ventas = new ArrayList<>();

        try(ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("ventas.dat"))) 
        {
            ventas = (ArrayList<Venta>) inputStream.readObject();
        } 
        catch (EOFException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error", "Se alcanzó el final del archivo inesperadamente.");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","Error de E/S al leer el archivo.");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","No se encontró la clase.");
        }

        return ventas;
    }
    
    
  public static ArrayList<Compra> leerCompras() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
  {
        ArrayList<Compra> compras = new ArrayList<>();

        try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("compras.dat"))) 
        {
            compras = (ArrayList<Compra>) inputStream.readObject();
        } 
        catch (EOFException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error", "Se alcanzó el final del archivo inesperadamente.");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","Error de E/S al leer el archivo.");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error","No se encontró la clase.");
        }

        return compras;
}
    
    /*ESCRITURA EN DISCO*/
    
    public static void escribirUsuarios(ArrayList<Usuarios> arr) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
      
      
      if (fichUsuarios.exists())
      {
          try (FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fichUsuarios); ObjectOutputStream regUsuario = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut)) {
              
                  try
                  {
                    regUsuario.writeObject(arr);
                  }catch (IOException e)
                  {
                    new VentanaError("Hubo algún problema al escribir fichero de usuarios en disco").setVisible(true);
                   
                  }
           
              
              fOut.close();
              regUsuario.close();
          }      
      }
                 
      
    }
    
    public static void escribirArticulos(ArrayList<Productos> arr) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
      
      
      if (fichArticulos.exists())
      {
          try (FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fichArticulos); ObjectOutputStream regUsuario = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut)) {
              
                 try
                  {
                    regUsuario.writeObject(arr);
                  }catch (IOException e)
                  {
                    new VentanaError("Hubo algún problema al escribir fichero de artículos en disco").setVisible(true);
              
                  }
                            
              fOut.close();
              regUsuario.close();
          }      
      }
                 
      
    }
    
    public static void escribirClientes(ArrayList<Clientes> arr) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
      
      
      if (fichClientes.exists())
      {
          try (FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fichClientes); ObjectOutputStream regUsuario = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut)) {
              
                  try
                  {
                    regUsuario.writeObject(arr);
                  }catch (IOException e)
                  {
                    new VentanaError("Hubo algún problema al escribir fichero de clientes en disco").setVisible(true);
                    
                  }
           
              
              fOut.close();
              regUsuario.close();
          }      
      }
                 
      
    }
    
    
    public static void escribirProveedores(ArrayList<Proveedores> arr) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
      
      
      if (fichProveedores.exists())
      {
          try (FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fichProveedores); ObjectOutputStream regUsuario = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut)) {
              
                  try
                  {
                    regUsuario.writeObject(arr);
                  }catch (IOException e)
                  {
                   new VentanaError("Hubo algún problema al escribir fichero de proveedores en disco").setVisible(true);   
                  }
             
              
              fOut.close();
              regUsuario.close();
          }      
      }
                 
      
    }
    
    
    public static void escribirVentas(ArrayList<Venta> arr) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
      
      
      if (fichVentas.exists())
      {
          try (FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fichVentas); ObjectOutputStream regUsuario = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut)) {
              
                  try
                  {
                    regUsuario.writeObject(arr);
                  }catch (IOException e)
                  {
                    new VentanaError("Hubo algún problema al escribir fichero de ventas en disco").setVisible(true);   
                  }
             
              
              fOut.close();
              regUsuario.close();
          }      
      }
                 
      
    }
    
    public static void escribirCompras(ArrayList<Compra> arr) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
      
      
      if (fichCompras.exists())
      {
          try (FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fichCompras); ObjectOutputStream regUsuario = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut)) {
              
                 try
                  {
                    regUsuario.writeObject(arr);
                  }catch (IOException e)
                  {
                   new VentanaError("Hubo algún problema al escribir fichero de compras en disco").setVisible(true);   
                  }
              
              
                fOut.close();
                regUsuario.close();
            }
        }

    }
     public static void cr``your text``eateFileIfNotExists(String filePath) {
        createFileIfNotExists(new File(filePath));
    }

    public static void createFileIfNotExists(File file) {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            // Perform any necessary initialization or data population for the file
        } catch (IOException e) {
            FuncionesGraficas.mostrarDatos("Error", "Error al crear el archivo: " + file.getPath());
        }
    }
}
}

```

`


/* THIS IS THE CODE THAT I HAVE TO WRITE AND READ ON THE FILES */


# /*
exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) @ ProyectoUsuarios2 ---

Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException

at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2929)

at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3424)

at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:983)

at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:414)

at com.mycompany.proyectousuarios2.ProyectoUsuarios2.leerUsuariosApp(ProyectoUsuarios2.java:91)

at com.mycompany.proyectousuarios2.ProyectoUsuarios2.main(ProyectoUsuarios2.java:67)

Command execution failed.

org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)

at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)

at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:1000)

at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:947)

at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:471)

at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)

at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)

at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)

at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)

at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)

at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)

at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)

at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)

at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)

at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)

at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)

at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  5.244 s
Finished at: 2023-06-08T13:17:52+02:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) on project ProyectoUsuarios2: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException*/
````